# How to validate duplicates for dynamically added form field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a from called verification form and a form array called RepDetails with three fields. By default the form shows three fields. User can add more details by clicking on add more. Now I want to check Mydetails[0].name should not match with mydetails[1].name. Can anyone help on this

```
Myform = this.fb.group({   
    Mydetails: this.fb.array([this.createMydetails()])   
  });

createMydetails(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      Myname: ['', Validators.required ],
      Myid: ['', Validators.required],
      Myphone: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Html

```
<div
        formArrayName="Mydetails"
        *ngFor="let item of Mydetails.controls; let i = index"
      >
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label class="required">
              Name
            </mat-label>
            <input
              appAlphaNumeric
              [maxlength]="maxRepNamelen"
              formControlName="Myname"
              class="mat-body-1"
              matInput
            />
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label class="required">
              Id
            </mat-label>
            <input
              appAlphaNumeric
             
              formControlName="Myid"
              class="mat-body-1"
              matInput
            />
          </mat-form-field>
          <div class="phn-wrapper">
            <ngx-intl-tel-input
              [cssClass]="'int-phn'"
              [searchCountryField]="[
                SearchCountryField.Iso2,
                SearchCountryField.Name
              ]"name="phone"
              formControlName="Myphone"
            >
            </ngx-intl-tel-input>
          </div>
          <mat-icon
            *ngIf="Mydetails.length > 1"
            (click)="remove(i)"
            class="close"
            >close</mat-icon
          >
          
        </div>
      </div>
        class="add-fields"
        (click)="add()"
      >
        <mat-icon class="icon">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
        <span class="text mat-button">
          {{"ADD MORE"}}</span
        >
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046298/want-to-add-a-custom-validation-with-angular-reactive-form-nested-form/63048387#63048387) you has a custom validation over a FormArray. The problem if you use a custom validation over a formArray is that is checked always you change any value in the formArray (any change in repName, or in passport or in phoneName)

You can create a custom validator over a Form Control that take account others controls

```
  checkIfUnique(index) {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
      //try get the form array
      //control.parent is the FormGroup, control.parent.parent is the formArray
      const formArray =
        control.parent && control.parent.parent
          ? (control.parent.parent as FormArray)
          : null;
      if (formArray && formArray.controls.length) {
        for (let i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (
            (formArray.at(i) as FormGroup).get("repName").value == control.value
          )
            return { errorRepeat: true };
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

You need, when make the formGroup of the formArray, pass to the validator the "index" of element. So your need change your function createRep

```
//pass the index
createRep(index:number): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      repName: ['', [Validators.required,this.checkIfUnique(index) ]],
      passport: ['', Validators.required],
      phoneNumber: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Well, the last we need is, when change a value of any 'repName', check the rest of controls. Remember that Angular check the formControl that you change, but not the rest, so if `repName[0]="a"` and `repName[1]="b"`, when change `repName[0]` to "b" Angular don't check `repName[1]`. So we create a function

```
  checkFormArray()
  {
    this.detailsFormArray.controls.forEach(x=>{
      (x as FormGroup).get('repName').updateValueAndValidity()
    })
  }
  //I use a getter of the formArray
  get detailsFormArray() {
     return (this.verificationForm.get("repDetails") as FormArray)
  }
```

And in the input we call to the function

```
  <input formControlName="repName" (input)="checkFormArray()">
```

You can [see the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pnqdzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: I remove the tag angularjs from your question (your question is only about angular)

Comment: Thanks for help @Eliseo